# How does Python 3 multiprocessing Pool know when to pick another set of values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I have my own package and want to paralelize the tasks it is doing.
I need to open session, execute query and close session in single worker.
Having example from multiprocessing documentation, the script looks like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from OwnDB import odb

def worker(y):
    session = odb('db_name', 'user', 'password')
    print(session)
    result = session.query("select name from table")
    session.disconnect()
    return [y, result]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
    with Pool(processes=2) as p:
        print(p.map(worker, test_nums))
```

This code, without openning and closing the session works as expected. However when I execute it with the session code, I get results only for the first set of pool workers (in this case 2) and then it runs till I kill it.

My assumption is that the multiprocessing package does not know when the worker is done - why could this be? How the worker indicates that it finished?

Comment: Maybe some of your workers hang on connecting to your DB or on executing queries. Have you tried simple print-trace/log after every call to your DB code to see if it ever gets to returning the result? Keep in mind that not all modules are multiprocessing/multithreading aware and may require additional coaxing to make them work in such setups.

Comment: Had the same idea, but even if I remove the query execution, do only connect and disconnect and after the disconnect add print statemet, only the first batch gets executed. If I raise the number of processes to say 4, I se 4x the expected output. Interestingly when I use apply_async, all works nicely.

Comment: Provided that you change `doc_get` in your `Pool.map()` call to `worker` and clear out the `OwnDB` code from it ought to work perfectly fine, unless you're running some very exotic version of Python or you have some process listener that grabs and sandboxes your processes.

Comment: Yes the doc_get name was original function name, I changed it to worker for better understanding - good catch :)
The aim of the question is to understand the inner workings of Pool.map(), so that I can find out if the module needs to be changed for multiprocessing.

Comment: Essentially, `map()` maps every of the passed iterable's items to a process to be called and then calls them one by one as soon as there is a free process in the pool. The process is considered free once the called function returns or errors. It's useful for quick and easy split of processing but it has a lot of shortcomings - for example it will consume your whole iterable and you have to wait until everything finishes with no indication of progress. You're much better of handling your own pool through the `apply_async()` method than relying on `.map()` for anything even moderately complex.

Comment: Add the Output of  `print('Start worker #{} Process:{}'.format(y, os.get_pid()))` to your Question.